# How to scrape table off a website in dataframe format?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried scraping a table of the NBA site but got the error no tables found.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.nba.com/game/0022101100/play-by-play?latest=0'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

How do I go about getting the play-by-play table?

Comment: You have `selenium` tagged, you should be using it instead of `requests`, as the table is dynamically generated via Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, that data is dynamically rendered. You could a) use Selenium to simulate opeing the browser, allowing the page to render, THEN use pandas to parse the table tags. or b) use the nba api and get the data in json format.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

gameId = '0022101100'
url = f'https://cdn.nba.com/static/json/liveData/playbyplay/playbyplay_{gameId}.json'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData,
                       record_path=['game', 'actions'])
```

**Here is Option 2:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json


gameId = '0021900709'
url = f'https://www.nba.com/game/{gameId}/play-by-play'
headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

jsonStr = soup.find('script', {'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}).text
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)['props']['pageProps']['playByPlay']
df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData,
                       record_path=['actions'])
```

**Output: first 10 rows of 548**

```
print(df.head(10).to_markdown())
|    |   actionNumber | clock       | timeActual             |   period | periodType   | actionType   | subType   | qualifiers           |   personId |        x |        y |   possession |   scoreHome |   scoreAway | edited               |   orderNumber |   xLegacy |   yLegacy |   isFieldGoal | side   | description                                            | personIdsFilter           |        teamId | teamTricode   | descriptor   | jumpBallRecoveredName   |   jumpBallRecoverdPersonId | playerName   | playerNameI    | jumpBallWonPlayerName   |   jumpBallWonPersonId | jumpBallLostPlayerName   |   jumpBallLostPersonId |   shotDistance | shotResult   |   pointsTotal | assistPlayerNameInitial   |   assistPersonId |   assistTotal |   officialId |   foulPersonalTotal |   foulTechnicalTotal | foulDrawnPlayerName   |   foulDrawnPersonId |   shotActionNumber |   reboundTotal |   reboundDefensiveTotal |   reboundOffensiveTotal |   turnoverTotal |   stealPlayerName |   stealPersonId |   blockPlayerName |   blockPersonId |   value |
|---:|---------------:|:------------|:-----------------------|---------:|:-------------|:-------------|:----------|:---------------------|-----------:|---------:|---------:|-------------:|------------:|------------:|:---------------------|--------------:|----------:|----------:|--------------:|:-------|:-------------------------------------------------------|:--------------------------|--------------:|:--------------|:-------------|:------------------------|---------------------------:|:-------------|:---------------|:------------------------|----------------------:|:-------------------------|-----------------------:|---------------:|:-------------|--------------:|:--------------------------|-----------------:|--------------:|-------------:|--------------------:|---------------------:|:----------------------|--------------------:|-------------------:|---------------:|------------------------:|------------------------:|----------------:|------------------:|----------------:|------------------:|----------------:|--------:|
|  0 |              2 | PT12M00.00S | 2022-03-25T23:10:44.0Z |        1 | REGULAR      | period       | start     | []                   |          0 | nan      | nan      |            0 |           0 |           0 | 2022-03-25T23:10:44Z |         20000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | Period Start                                           | []                        | nan           | nan           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | nan          | nan            | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | nan          |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  1 |              4 | PT11M55.00S | 2022-03-25T23:10:47.2Z |        1 | REGULAR      | jumpball     | recovered | []                   |    1626220 | nan      | nan      |   1610612762 |           0 |           0 | 2022-03-25T23:10:47Z |         40000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | Jump Ball R. Gobert vs. M. Plumlee: Tip to R. O'Neale  | [1626220, 203497, 203486] |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | startperiod  | R. O'Neale              |                1.62622e+06 | O'Neale      | R. O'Neale     | Gobert                  |                203497 | Plumlee                  |                 203486 |         nan    | nan          |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  2 |              7 | PT11M36.00S | 2022-03-25T23:11:06.3Z |        1 | REGULAR      | 2pt          | DUNK      | ['pointsinthepaint'] |     203497 |  92.8548 |  47.0588 |   1610612762 |           0 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:11:12Z |         70000 |       -15 |        15 |             1 | right  | R. Gobert DUNK (2 PTS) (D. Mitchell 1 AST)             | [203497, 1628378]         |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | Gobert       | R. Gobert      | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |           2.08 | Made         |             2 | D. Mitchell               |      1.62838e+06 |             1 |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  3 |              9 | PT11M21.00S | 2022-03-25T23:11:25.8Z |        1 | REGULAR      | foul         | personal  | ['2freethrow']       |     203497 | nan      | nan      |   1610612766 |           0 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:11:38Z |         90000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | R. Gobert shooting personal FOUL (1 PF) (Plumlee 2 FT) | [203497, 203486]          |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | shooting     | nan                     |              nan           | Gobert       | R. Gobert      | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | nan          |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |       200832 |                   1 |                    0 | Plumlee               |              203486 |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  4 |             11 | PT11M21.00S | 2022-03-25T23:11:50.7Z |        1 | REGULAR      | freethrow    | 1 of 2    | []                   |     203486 | nan      | nan      |   1610612766 |           0 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:11:50Z |        110000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | MISS M. Plumlee Free Throw 1 of 2                      | [203486]                  |   1.61061e+09 | CHA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | Plumlee      | M. Plumlee     | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | Missed       |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  5 |             12 | PT11M21.00S | 2022-03-25T23:11:50.7Z |        1 | REGULAR      | rebound      | offensive | ['deadball', 'team'] |          0 | nan      | nan      |   1610612766 |           0 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:11:50Z |        120000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | TEAM offensive REBOUND                                 | []                        |   1.61061e+09 | CHA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | nan          | nan            | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | nan          |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                 11 |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  6 |             13 | PT11M21.00S | 2022-03-25T23:12:06.4Z |        1 | REGULAR      | freethrow    | 2 of 2    | []                   |     203486 | nan      | nan      |   1610612766 |           1 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:12:06Z |        130000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | M. Plumlee Free Throw 2 of 2 (1 PTS)                   | [203486]                  |   1.61061e+09 | CHA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | Plumlee      | M. Plumlee     | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | Made         |             1 | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  7 |             14 | PT11M06.00S | 2022-03-25T23:12:22.2Z |        1 | REGULAR      | 3pt          | Jump Shot | []                   |    1626220 |  69.7273 |  75.2451 |   1610612762 |           1 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:12:29Z |        140000 |       126 |       232 |             1 | right  | MISS R. O'Neale 26' 3PT                                | [1626220]                 |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | O'Neale      | R. O'Neale     | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |          26.42 | Missed       |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  8 |             15 | PT11M02.00S | 2022-03-25T23:12:26.2Z |        1 | REGULAR      | rebound      | offensive | []                   |    1627823 | nan      | nan      |   1610612762 |           1 |           2 | 2022-03-25T23:12:29Z |        150000 |       nan |       nan |             0 |        | J. Hernangomez REBOUND (Off:1 Def:0)                   | [1627823]                 |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | Hernangomez  | J. Hernangomez | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |         nan    | nan          |           nan | nan                       |    nan           |           nan |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                 14 |              1 |                       0 |                       1 |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
|  9 |             16 | PT10M56.00S | 2022-03-25T23:12:33.1Z |        1 | REGULAR      | 3pt          | Jump Shot | ['2ndchance']        |    1628378 |  68.6761 |  70.098  |   1610612762 |           1 |           5 | 2022-03-25T23:12:38Z |        160000 |       100 |       242 |             1 | right  | D. Mitchell 26' 3PT  (3 PTS) (J. Hernangomez 1 AST)    | [1628378, 1627823]        |   1.61061e+09 | UTA           | nan          | nan                     |              nan           | Mitchell     | D. Mitchell    | nan                     |                   nan | nan                      |                    nan |          26.19 | Made         |             3 | J. Hernangomez            |      1.62782e+06 |             1 |          nan |                 nan |                  nan | nan                   |                 nan |                nan |            nan |                     nan |                     nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |               nan |             nan |     nan |
```

Comment: thanks where the f do you learn this? For example, how did you find that URL link?

Comment: You can usually find this by using dev tools (shift-ctrl-i) then looking in Network -> XHR and find where the request was made.

Comment: This particular case i actually couldn’t find it, however I’ve used nba.com api in the past, so I e had sone references to it in other parts of code I’ve used.

Comment: very impressive

Comment: thnx. Like I said, Selenium would have worked here, but that's usually a last resort for me. Go in this order 1) check for api, 2) check if data in a `<script>` tag in json format in the html reponse 3a) if no api, data is static, and its a `<table>` tag, use pandas `.read_html()`, 3b) same as above, but also need links or other attributes in table, use bs4, 4) if no api, data is static, and not a `<table>` tag, use bs4 5) all else fails, use Selenium (then check options 2-4)

Comment: @chittown88 sorry to bother you again but I get the error 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value'  for game_id = "0021900709" ?  Any ideas?

Comment: Ya interesting. If you put that into the browser, it returns access denied. So potentially IP getting blocked. Let me look into it further.

Comment: ya slightly annoying. SO in this case (if you look at my comment above), we can go to my option `2`, since the json is also in the response html in the `<script>` tag. See edit in my solution above

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded dynamically via API as json format.So you can extract them using json() and pandas as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
api_url = 'https://cdn.cookielaw.org/vendorlist/iab2Data.json'
headers= {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    }

req=requests.get(api_url,headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(req)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
 gvlSpecificationVersion  tcfPolicyVersion  ... vendorListVersion           lastUpdated
1                           2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
2                           2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
3                           2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
4                           2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
5                           2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
...                       ...               ...  ...               ...                   ...
1146                        2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
1147                        2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
1148                        2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
1149                        2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z
1150                        2                 2  ...               159  2022-09-01T16:05:33Z

[907 rows x 10 columns]
```